# how to used cordova jspdf to generate the pdf and save in local

Tags: android, cordova, jspdf, phonegap

I'm working on an phonegap android app where I need to generate a pdf file based on user input, so I choosed jsPDF to generate the pdf file. Noting that the app when tested on a web browser it's working well, however when tested on an android emulator I got the following error:

> LocalFileSystem is not defined

I have used this code

```
//FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
console.log("generating pdf...");
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

var pdfOutput = doc.output();
console.log( pdfOutput );

//NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
console.log("file system...");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

   console.log(fileSystem.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
   console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

   fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
      var fileEntry = entry;
      console.log(entry);

      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
         writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("write success");
      };

      console.log("writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });

   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
},
function(event){
 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
});
```

Comment: Looks like this is missing an [mcve]. Perhaps readers would need to see your stack trace and code in the question itself?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.